# If column 2 of file2 is diferent than column2 of file1 print column1 from file1 and column2 from both files

Tags: text-processing, awk, join

I have two unsorted files, each with two columns. For any line in file1 whose column1 value matches that of any line in file2, but whose column 2 values differ, I want to print the column 1 value and each column 2 value.

If data from column1 in file 1 does not exist in file2 it can be discarded. I do not need to preserve the sort order in the output file.

```
file1: 

2222,b2
4444,d4
1111,a1
3333,c3
5555,e5

file2:

2222,8f
5555,e9
4444,7c
3333,c3


OUTPUT file:
2222,b2,8f
4444,d4,7c
5555,e5,e9
```

Comment: I think you have a typo in the title of your question: You mean "If column 2 of file**1** is diferent"?

Comment: @don_crissti Us people thank you for the constructive criticism. ~fixed.

Comment: Doh! Ok its actually fixed now. :)

Comment: If a *key* (ie. column 1 value) exists in only one file, what do you want do? Print it? Discard it?

Comment: @user1404316 If it doesn't exist in file2 it can be discarded

Comment: @don_crissti no, I dont need to preserve the order.

Comment: @Jdubyas - I just made a major edit to your question, for clarity, but a question remains: What if there are multiple lines in either file with the same value for column 1, eg 2 lines in file 1 and 3 lines in file 2? Is that a possibility in the question? If so, how should it be handles?

Comment: @user1404316 Thank you for the edit. There will not be more than one one instance of the column1 data in each file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read the 2nd file, save the content into an array (key = 1st field, value = 2nd field) then read the 1st file and check if 1st field is a common key and if the corresponding 2nd field is different. If the result is positive, print the key and the two values:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","}NR==FNR{z[$1]=$2;next}
{if (z[$1] && (z[$1]!=$2)){print $0, z[$1]}}' file2 file1
```

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: The question as originally written was quite unclear and lacked important details. What follows are the original two answers I wrote as the question developed in clarity. The answers are good for similar simpler cases to the question as currently written.

1. For a case of sorted and matching files, I would recommend first using the command line utility `paste` to create a temporary third file which would be file with with column two of file two added to each line. Pipe the output of this `paste` command to `awk`, and then your `awk` solution becomes trivial - `$2 != $4{printf "%s %s %s", $1, $2, $4}`.

   paste -d"," file1 file2 | awk 'BEGIN{FS=",";OFS=","}$2 != $4{printf "%s,%s,%s", $1, $2, $4}'
2. For a case of unsorted matched files, if all the *keys* of file1 and fil2 are identical, just `sort` the input to the `paste`. You can do this kind of thing in the `bash` shell, using *process substitution*, with the form `<( command )`, as in the example below:

   paste -d"," <( sort file1 )  <( sort file2 ) | awk 'BEGIN{FS=",";OFS=","}$2 != $4{printf "%s,%s,%s", $1, $2, $4}'
3. For an unsorted and unmatched set of files (the question as currently written), see user don_crissti's answer.

Comment: Both files are unsorted and column1 may or may not be in both files, but column1 from file1 would be the data I need to match against

Comment: Your example input in the question **was** sorted, so maybe change that in your question or mention it clearly in the question text ... Anyway, all columns 1 entries in file1 do have a corresponding entry in file 2, just `sort` each file going into the `paste`, eg. `<( $(sort file1)`)` instead of `file1`.

Comment: @Jdubyas : oops, I had the syntax of the process substitution wrong. It should be `<( sort a1 ) `. Added to answer...

Comment: I am getting empty results when running this. The paste command is producing this output:

1111,a1,2222,8f
2222,b2,3333,c3
3333,c3,4444,7c
4444,d4,5555,e9
5555,e5,

Comment: @Jdubyas : That's because it was written before I was aware that not all entries for column 1 exist in both files. If you have a match for all column 1 entries in both files, it *should* work. Try it as a proof of concept.

Comment: Sorry about the confusion, thanks for helping me clarify the question and your answers @user1404316 !

Answer (score -1):

Can I use join ?

```
sort -o file1 file1 
sort -o file2 file2 
join -t"," -1 1 -2 1 file1 file2 | awk '$2!=$3'
```